# I found issue in getting cordinates of Forms To Stop Graphics to cross it

Tags: c#, .net, graphics, drawing

In windows form application i create a graphics Box or Ellipse, i want this graphics do not get out from the form when i start to move it on runtime, one way i got this idea to implement is to get X and Y coordinates of form and match it from the x and y coordinates of my graphic object but it is not working properly i think x and y coordinates of forms are not correct.

Following are the code that i use to detect eighter the graphic are inside the form or outside from it.

```
float formX = this.Location.X;
float formY = this.Location.Y;
float formWidth = this.Width;
float formHeight = this.Height;

// x = my graphic x's coordinates
// y = my graphic y's coordinates 
// width = the width of my graphic or the x2 values of my graphic

if ((x > (formX + formWidth) || ((x + width) > (formX + formWidth))
   return true;
else
   return false;
```

i just mentioned here simple code and only with x axis, it is not worked properly the (`formX` + `width` ) is greater even when graphics are showed at the corner of the form.

I hope you got my point please suggest what to do to get out from this.

Answer (score 0):

When the image is off the left edge of the form, the x coordinate of the relevant edge will be less than formX.  When it's off the right side of the form, it'll be greater than formX + formWidth, so the comparison in the first half of the condition is the wrong way round - and is comparing to the wrong value:

```
if ((x < formX) || ((x + width) > (formX + formWidth)))
   return true;
else
   return false;
```

At least, I'm assuming that's what you want, it's possible the logic is inverted from what you're after, but that's easily fixed.

You can also clean it up slightly, as the if-else statements are not required:

```
return (x < formX) || ((x + width) > (formX + formWidth));
```

Comment: thanks for the answering but Gonul i have tested my conditions, i got it as well what you were said but actually the problem is that the value of formX (the left edge of the form) is 175, this is the problem for me, it shouldn't be zero ? if no than y? please let me know

Comment: From http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms159414.aspx: Form.Location Gets or sets the Point that represents the upper-left corner of the Form **in screen coordinates**. In other words, it's the distance of the left hand edge from the left hand edge of the screen.

Comment: I don't know what library you're using for graphics, but you need to figure out whether the x and y of the graphic you're moving is relative to the screen, or to the form - if it's the latter, then you need to be comparing it to `0` and `formWidth`.